# DocFX offline documentation

Tags: c#, html, .net, documentation, docfx

Is there a way to deploy DocFX generated documentation as offline webpage? Currently I need to serve it on localhost to view it. Without it, I have the single pages for each class but I cant navigate through them etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite new to DocFX and this was a pain in the neck for me until... a few minutes ago.

If you are generating the documentation from Visual Studio (like I do), in the docfx.json file, change the template to "statictoc":

```
"template": [
  "statictoc"
]
```

Then build the project again and you should be able to have a full offline documentation (that did the trick for me).

I also found this issue (closed): https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/4578

Hope this helps!

***EDIT***: I just found a reference also in the official DocFx documentation, in the Templates section: https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/templates-and-plugins/templates-dashboard.html

Answer (score 0):

Install the IIS components and deploy your site on it, adding a new application. Make the folder with the build results outside the DocFx project folder, for example "dest": "../IISApp/products/docs-learn/".
You can use any templates without restrictions. And also give a link to the site to other users within the network, replacing "localhost" with the name of the workstation.